# Difference between kubectl and minikube-kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm using Mac OS for development environment.

If I install `minikube`, the `kubectl` will use the local cluster made by `minikube` as a default option. I found I can use `kubectl` command with `minikube` prefix - just like below:

```sh
$ minikube kubectl get pods
```

So I tried it, and `kubectl` download process began. So I can get that the `kubectl` in my Mac and the `kubectl` in `minikube` is not identical. But what does thie mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a wrapper for kubectl, downloading it when not installed, otherwise executing the client.

See the command with '--help' below.

> **$ minikube kubectl --help**
>
> Run the kubernetes client, download it if necessary.
>
> Usage:
> minikube kubectl [flags]
>
> Flags:
> -h, --help   help for kubectl
>
> Global Flags:
>
> [...]